# Do private airports have to have the same runway and taxiway dimension and separation requirements as public airports?

Tags: general-aviation, airport-design

I'm new to this site. I joined today after searching for hours to find answers to this question with no luck.

I am a part of a group of pilots and aviation enthusiasts working on a new aviation community development project. We have done extensive research and have collected a ton of data on various aspects of building an aviation community. However, we haven't had much luck finding definitive answers to the above question. I will elaborate more on the question...

Specifically, I would like to know if there are any requirements and/or regulations to follow with respect to the following for runways and taxiways in a private aviation community, or is it up to the discretion of the developers/owners to decide?

1. Runway width and length requirements
2. Runway Safety Area
3. Runway Blast Pad
4. Runway Object Free Area
5. Runway Shoulder
6. Runway Protection Zone
7. Runway Centerline to Taxiway Centerline separation
8. Taxiway width requirements
9. Taxiway Safety Area
10. Taxiway Shoulder

As I said, I tried for some time to research this, but all I can find is data for public airports. Nothing for private ones. If anyone can provide the answer or point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the site! It sounds like a great project, what regulatory jurisdiction is it in, i.e. what country?

Comment: If your proposed airport is in the U.S., you might get the information you need from an FAA Airports District Office (ADO). This is a link to the FAA website that has the contact information for the various ADO's in the U.S. https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/arp/offices/regional_offices

Comment: Yes GdD, we are all very much excited about this project and can't wait to start the development and building process. Currently, we are about to make an offer on a parcel of land in the Caribbean. That is our first option as everyone in our group are retired or semi-retired and prefer the tropics. If that deal falls through, then our next option is in the US preferably Florida

Comment: 757toga, thank you for the link. I will give them a call tomorrow.

Comment: I finally managed to speak to the right person at the Orlando ADO - a Mr. Scott Cararro. He was very helpful. In a nutshell, as far as the FAA goes, private airports are not obligated to follow any requirements as public airports do. He said the FAA is mostly concerned with the airspace above the airport, and what happens on the private property is up to the owners/operators and the FDOT. He did say however, it is highly recommended to follow the public airport requirements, especially if larger private aircraft like the G650 and G700 will be using the private airport. Thanks again 757toga.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the United Kingdom, the document [CAP 168](https://publicapps.caa.co.uk/modalapplication.aspx?appid=11&mode=detail&id=6114) outlines the requirements you must meet to have your aerodrome licensed by the CAA. In other countries there will likely be similar documents.

The requirements for "public" and "private" (referred to as "ordinary" by the CAA) aerodromes do not differ.

If you don't want your aerodrome to be licensed by the CAA then you don't need to meet their criteria, but some insurers won't let you fly to/from unlicensed aerodromes.

Comment: Yes opr, I thought so too. But when I researched some of the existing aviation communities in the US, there was no consistency with respect to this topic. Some even had a parallel taxiway only 70 feet from the runway. It didn't seem like they were ahering to any regulations or guidelines.